# How can I change mouse and touchpad settings?

Tags: 14.04, mouse-scroll, vmware-workstation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on VMWare. The mouse and touch settings which I have for Windows 8.1 like the 2 finger scroll is not present in Ubuntu. Is there any way to add that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Just type on the Dash: Mouse. Then select the option "Mouse and Touchpad". In the opened window, select the tab "Touchpad". There you can check the 2 finger scroll option and more.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring mouse settings under Ubuntu is easy.

If you open up your dash by hitting the win key and type in just as the previous responder commented "mouse" (you can do that even in your own language if it's other than English) depending on your desktop environment you should be able to see the following:

[image: Mouse settings]

My screenshot refers to Ubuntu GNOME (GNOME 3.14).

Alternatively you can, if on Unity, hit the top right icon of a wrench typically, look for **system settings** and from there **mouse and touchpad settings**.